# JDBC Query error

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

I want to save the list of tables for JDBC to count one by one and I wrote a program for this  but problem is when I execute this code it works but it directly goes to exception. When I debug, it says that on line "SimpleDTO[] dtoLar =" "Runner can not be resolved". What does this mean? I identified it before  as  QueryRunner as can be seen from the code below. So is it posible that it can not be resolved?

```
QueryRunner Runner = new QueryRunner();

        SimpleDTO tableCount = null, currentTimeStr = null;

        SimpleDTO[] dtoLar = (SimpleDTO[]) Runner.query(connORA,
                SQL_SELECT_NAMES_OF_TABLES_RR, null, new BeanListHandler(
                        SimpleDTO.class))
```

This is my SimpeDTO Class to get rows in table list.

```
import java.io.Serializable;  

public class SimpleDTO implements Serializable{

String value = null;

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}



}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's a type but the first line (QueryRunner Runner = new QueryRunner();) should be QueryRunner runner = new QueryRunner(); (no capital letter for 'runner')

Comment: I changed it but it still tells the same message.

Comment: Did you also changed it in the line that produces the error (SimpleDTO[] dtoLar = (SimpleDTO[]) runner.query(connORA, )?

Comment: Yes I changed it also it still doesn't work. MAybe class cast exception problem? Can I cast it to array (SimpleDTO[])?